# Java Array user input

Tags: java, arrays

What do i have to do to give all the dim variables int saint a diffrent value with the help of a user input?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int dim = in.nextInt();
int[] saint = new int[dim];
```

Comment: Explain it in more details

Comment: Code a loop from 0 to dim, ask the user for an int in each iteration

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `for` loop for that.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)//loop from 0 to dim
{
 System.out.println("Enter a value for the " + i + "th index"); 
 saint[i] = in.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(saint));
```